# Border for rounded rectangle of UIView is not spreaded over the edges. Xamarin IOS

Tags: swift, xamarin.ios

I have Created UIView , I need to change topleft and Bottom Left with rounded edges.I have provided with border color and width. But Border for rounder rectangle of that UIView is not spreaded over the edges.

```
     view.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0,36,36);
        var maskLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
        maskLayer.Path = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(view.Bounds, (UIRectCorner.TopLeft | UIRectCorner.BottomLeft), new CoreGraphics.CGSize(36.0,36.0)).CGPath;
        maskLayer.Bounds = m_scrollHead.Frame;


        view.Layer.Mask = maskLayer;

        view.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        view.Layer.BorderColor = new CoreGraphics.CGColor(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Make masklayer a globally scoped variabel and update its frame in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method. Something like maskLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: view.bounds.size).

Comment: No its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the **BorderWidth**  and **BorderColor** on **maskLayer** because the view will clip the border if you set them on layer.

Refer the following code:

```
UIView view = new UIView();
view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
view.Frame = new CGRect(30, 100, 36, 36);
var maskLayer = new CAShapeLayer();

UIBezierPath bezierPath = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(view.Bounds, (UIRectCorner.TopLeft | UIRectCorner.BottomLeft), new CGSize(18.0, 18.0));


maskLayer.Path = bezierPath.CGPath;
maskLayer.Frame = view.Bounds;

maskLayer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor; //set the borderColor
maskLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;   //set the background color
maskLayer.LineWidth = 1;  //set the border width

view.Layer.AddSublayer(maskLayer);

View.AddSubview(view);
```

[image]

Comment: Super Bro. Its Working Now.

Comment: Happy coding :)